# Download Manager keeps downloading the first apk and caches it

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I am using DownloadManager and it is working as well for the first time. There is a link which will always give me the last-version.apk, but after updating apk download manager keeps downloading the first apk. For example, I downloaded the last-version.apk which is version 1 then the server will upload apk to version 2, but the download manager keeps downloading version 1.

I tried to uninstall and clear data, but still downloading version 1.
Note that if I install an application in a new phone it will download version 2, but it seems that the problem still exists

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the file already exists or not?

```
     String path = String.valueOf(getContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);

                    File file = new File(path);

                    if(file.isFile()){
                       // delete the old version
                    }
```

Comment: yes I have tired
, and I also renamed the newly-downloaded file, but still downloading the previous apk which is wrong because I can download new apk from browser!

Comment: Please try to clear cache and data on Play Store and Download Manager.